# Consuming JSON with Play Framework and $.ajax

Tags: ajax, json, rest, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm still new to RESTful APIs and JSON, so I tried looking at the documentation for jQuery and Play for [sending JSON to a URI](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [parsing JSON from a request body](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonRequests).

Unfortunately, I'm getting some unexpected behavior.

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "@routes.Application.downloadResults",
            data: {
                uuid: $('body').attr('uuid')
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(res) {
                console.log('success')
            },
            error: function(res) {
                console.log('error')
            }
        })
```

Here is my server code:

```
  def downloadResults = Action { request =>
    Logger.info("Attempting to download")
    Logger.info(request.toString)
    Logger.info(request.body.toString)
    Logger.info(request.body.asJson.toString)
    request.body.asJson.map { json =>
      {
    Logger.info(json.toString)
    json.validate[String].map {
      case uuid => {
        Logger.info(s"Looking for results-$uuid.txt")
        Ok.sendFile(new File(s"results-$uuid.txt"))
      }
    }.recoverTotal {
      e =>
        {
          Logger.info("Detected error: " + JsError.toFlatJson(e))
          BadRequest("Detected error: " + JsError.toFlatJson(e))
        }
    }
      }
    }.getOrElse {
      Logger.info("Expecting Json data")
      BadRequest("Expecting Json data")
    }
  }
```

Here is the resulting server log:

```
[info] application - Attempting to download
[info] application - GET /download?uuid=12512502-5ca4-47bc-a4db-15f1da1979fc
[info] application - AnyContentAsEmpty
[info] application - None
[info] application - Expecting Json data
```

Here is the resulting browser console:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/download?uuid=12512502-5ca4-47bc-a4db-15f1da1979fc 400 (Bad Request) jquery-1.9.0.min.js:3
error
```

It looks like the `uuid` is being attached to the URI as a parameter, but I was trying to send it as JSON.  I guess it doesn't really matter which way it gets there right now, but I'm trying to sharpen up my understanding of using JSON for client-server communication.  I tried calling `Json.stringify` on the JSON data, but that just resulted in `GET /download?{%22uuid%22:%224de4c3dd-24db-49dc-8f9e-4d3e0d90dea5%22}` in my server log.

Any tips on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery uses a GET method by default when using `$.ajax()`. That's why your content is appended to the URL.

You should try to add `type: "POST"` to you `$.ajax` call. This will tell jQuery to send your data in the request body, not in the URL.

Also, be sure that your route is declared with a POST method in your application `routes` config file.

Comment: Yes, this was my issue.  Thanks